# Issues with the mobile client for Stack Overflow

Tags: support, mobile-web

I'm typing this with my iPhone.

Code blocks get truncated and you can't scroll them either.

Is this local to Safari or to all small displays?

Comment: Sorry - ignore my close vote. I misread the question, partly due to the wrong tag being used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can indeed scroll them, use two fingers. Same on iPad.

Comment: Indeed you can.  I just didn't think to try two fingers on blocks of text that are 1 line high (it's hard to put two fingers on 10 pixels...)