# How should I format terminal output?

Tags: support, markdown, editor

I want to post some output from a terminal and ask a question.  How do you use the editor on Stack Overflow? It says that it must be in code format when I paste it in.

Comment: Look at the "Your Answer" box below.  Do you see the question mark in the upper right-hand corner?  Click that.

Comment: The "Editing and Formatting" section of [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7931/167443) should help you find your ansewr.

Comment: paste it, then select it and press Ctrl+K

Comment: Thanks Sai.  Easy solution.  I will look into the others. :)

Comment: Better duplicate: [Should console output be formatted as code sample or as blockquote?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/190092)/

Answer (score 3):

You use the button that looks like

> {}

just above where you enter your information.

You'll see a highlighted text in your message that says

> enter code here

paste your code there.